# Laravel - Class 'Setting' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 4.2 & getting `Class 'Setting' not found` error on my production server whereas it is working perfectly on my localhost. Here is my controller code (partial)

**Here is my controller code :**

```
<?php 
// app/controllers/ClaimController.php
class ClaimController extends \BaseController {
  public function create()
  {
    $insurers       = Insurer::lists('insurers_name', 'id');
    $office         = Office::lists('office_name', 'id');
    $workshops      = Workshop::lists('workshop_name', 'id');
    $type_of_report = Setting::where('grp','=','type_of_report')->lists('name','id');
    $vehicle_type   = Setting::where('grp','=','vehicle_type')->lists('name','id');

    return View::make('claim.create')->with('insurers',$insurers)->with('office',$office)->with('workshops',$workshops)->with('type_of_report', $type_of_report)->with('vehicle_type', $vehicle_type);
  }
}
```

**Model code :**

```
<?php
// app/models/setting.php
    class Setting extends Eloquent {
    }
?>
```

Getting this error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Class 'Setting' not found
```

When I change above two lines in create() function to

```
$type_of_report = DB::table('settings')->where('grp','type_of_report')->lists('name','id');
$vehicle_type   = DB::table('settings')->where('grp','vehicle_type')->lists('name','id');
```

works fine on production server & on my localhost.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a typo for Settings?

Comment: Yes, I rechecked, it's not a type.

Comment: Do you have a corresponding model file for settings table?

Comment: Try executing `php artisan optimize` on your production server

Comment: Hi @lukasgeiter, I executed artisan optimize command on production server but not working.

Comment: Hmm maybe try the `Setting::where...` in your routes.php file (just for testing) and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that your model file is named `setting.php` and it should be `Setting.php` with capital letter. On localhost (probably Windows) it will work without a problem because in Windows file `aaa` and `AAA` is the same but in Linux it isn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot @marcin for valuable suggestion. I renamed    Setting.php to    setting.php but with no luck. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @Aman It should have the same case as your classname. Your class name is `Setting` so the file should have name `Setting.php` and now you told you have opposite.